# Chainlink Goerli - MustBeSubOwner Revert on RequestRandomness

Tags: ethereum, chainlink

I followed the [direct funding tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/direct-funding/)

I am testing on goerli,
however still getting a revert ([tenderly tx explorer](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/goerli/0x4b1694ff9c50db0f50feeb16cd73204b761487b2b53f997c88392475e691e679/debugger?trace=0.8.2.0.3.0))
It is very weird, MustBeSubowner revert.
I dont quite understand it, as msg.sender is the wrapper, and when
i check the subscription owner, it is the wrapper (subId is 1519),
so it should not revert :/

This is how i did the init on goerli:

```
constructor(address stateAddress) VRFV2WrapperConsumerBase(
    0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB, // LINK Token
    0x708701a1DfF4f478de54383E49a627eD4852C816 // VRF Wrapper ) {
  keyHash = 0x79d3d8832d904592c0bf9818b621522c988bb8b0c05cdc3b15aea1b6e8db0c15;
  fee = 0.25 * 10 ** 18; // in LINK (Varies by network)
```

This should be ok right?

And i call then:

```
requestId = requestRandomness(3000000, 3, 1);
```

I also funded the calling contract with enough LINK
I got the params from:
https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/direct-funding/supported-networks/#goerli-testnet

I was expecting to get a fulfillRandomWords callback, but instead got a revert on requestRandomness call.

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Vedran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20419426/vedran-kajic)

If you compare your code with the [example](https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/VRF/VRFv2DirectFundingConsumer.sol) in [Create and deploy a VRF v2 compatible contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/direct-funding/examples/get-a-random-number/#create-and-deploy-a-vrf-v2-compatible-contract)

You are NOT initializing the
`ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)` in the `constructor` and you must do it.

Comment: Thanks, though the issue was actually in too high callback gas price (it should be under 2.5M).